# Display HTML contents in a row with next and back buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I tried to search for this topic with no luck.

I want to display content in my webpage in multiple rows and with each row, I want to have next and back buttons when the contents are more than the page width.

A good example is [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/)

[image]

I found good toturials about carousel, but I am not really looking for carousel or at least it doesn't look like what I am looking to implement.

I hope that I was able to explain my question

Comment: Got any code for us to take a look at?

Comment: Hi, not really because I am still confused on how to start. I am still looking and searching but I did not have any answer so far.

Comment: Why a carousel doesn't work for you?
There are multiple scripts out there wich should solve your problem.
For example you can try flexslider or something else.

And if thats not the solution please describe exaclty why not.

Comment: @MFGSparka Carousel not a good option because I am using bootstrap cards not images, I don't want to use the "next/back" buttons unless the contents are wider that the page width, and I don't want automatic sliding.

Comment: If you take a look to the bootstrap carousel documentation you can see that this script can solve your problme. But you have to do a little bit of javascript and css.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

-  you can use images or html....
-  you can only aktivate it if you have more cards than cards fit in your row

Please try it. And ask again if your stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I did something quite similarly in the past, I will try explain how I did it.

Firstly, here is the js fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/VoidZA/fxudjony/

It is something around the lines of:

```
<div class="container-holder">
    <div class="click-prev nav-button">Prev</div>
    <div class="outsideViewBefore container">Container Before</div>
    <div class="inView1 container">Container 1</div>
    <div class="inView2 container">Container 2</div>
    <div class="inView3 container">Container 3</div>
    <div class="inView4 container">Container 4</div>
    <div class="inView5 container">Container 5</div>
    <div class="outsideViewAfter container">Container After</div>
    <div class="click-next nav-button">Next</div>
</div>
```

edit final:
Fixed up the code, and put an example into jsFiddle

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. However, it didn't work when I tried the code you provided??

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/VoidZA/2j91o765/
There was a few mistakes here and there

Comment: Also, here is something a bit closer to what you were thinking about, just added the content, and some styling for the content:
https://jsfiddle.net/VoidZA/fxudjony/